# a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "RANDOMSTRUCT *"

Tags: c++, c

So I was working on malloc in void. And I have a code:

```
    int iInitRandomPhaseArrays(WS_ELEMENT *Aufbau, RANDOMSTRUCT **random)
{
    WS_ELEMENT *Act;
    int iCounter = 0, i;
    RANDOMSTRUCT *dummy;

    Act = Aufbau;

    if (*random != NULL)
        return -1;

    while (Act != NULL)
    {
        if (Act->operation == Linsenarray)
            iCounter++;
        Act = Act->pNext;
    }
    if (iCounter)
    {
        dummy = malloc(iCounter * sizeof(random));

        ran1_3ARG(&ran1_idum, &ran1_iy, ran1_iv);
        dummy[0].idum = ran1_idum;
        dummy[0].iy = ran1_iy;
        memcpy(dummy[0].iv, ran1_iv, sizeof(ran1_iv));

        for (i = 0; i < iCounter; i++)
            ran1_3ARG(&dummy[i].idum, &dummy[i].iy, dummy[i].iv);
        dummy[0].Anzahl = iCounter;
        *random = dummy;
    }



    return iCounter;
}
```

here error:

a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "RANDOMSTRUCT *"

Can anyone help me solve it?

Comment: Looks like you may be trying to compile C code as if it was C++ code.

Comment: The C language allows for automatic conversion of `void *` to any other kind of data pointer (such as you get from `malloc()`), but C++ requires an explicit cast.

Comment: i think it should be ```sizeof(**random)```

Comment: @PunyCode Or just `dummy = malloc(iCounter * sizeof(*dummy));`, so you don't have to figure out the correct type.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line:

```
dummy = malloc(iCounter * sizeof(random));
```

to say:

```
dummy = (RANDOMSTRUCT *)malloc(iCounter * sizeof(RANDOMSTRUCT));
```

Comment: If the language is supposed to be C, this is unnecessary. And if the language is supposed to be C++, then probably `malloc` should be `new` or `std::vector` instead. (Though I don't know what `RANDOMSTRUCT` is)

Comment: Sure, but the line was mallocing the wrong size of data anyway (the size of a pointer by the looks of it rather than the random structure), and it's just nice - even in C, to specify the return type of your malloc'd / realloc'd pointer. It's not necessary, but it's good for code readibility and clarity.

Answer (score 0):

```
dummy = malloc(iCounter * sizeof(random));
```

this allocates the wrong amount of memory (a multiple of a pointer size, not the pointed-to) and returns a `void*`.  In [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) `void*` doesn't implicitly convert to other pointer types.  In [c](/questions/tagged/c) it does.

Assuming you actually mean to use C-isms in C++ code, write this:

```
template<class T>
T* typed_malloc( std::size_t count = 1 ) {
  return static_cast<T*>(malloc( sizeof(T)*count ));
}
```

this function is a type-safe version of `malloc` that handles 9999/10000 uses, and prevents an annoying class of bugs.

Then change the line of code to:

```
dummy = typed_malloc<RANDOMSTRUCT>(iCounter);
```

Sometimes using `malloc` in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) isn't easy to remove, because your code interacts with [c](/questions/tagged/c) code.  This kind of change can eliminate bugs before they happen as you modify [c](/questions/tagged/c) code to [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) relatively transparently.