# Visual Studio C++ : a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to and entity of type "PMSG"

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

I am going through Charles Petzold - Programming Windows(5th Edition).  The example given has an error on Visual Studio 2019.  It seems to be a cast related issue with function type void * seems to be equated to a PMSG type.  And the compiler is unable to compile.

```
#include "framework.h"
#include "keyview1.h"

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
    static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT("KeyView1");
    HWND hwnd;
    MSG msg;
    WNDCLASS wndclass;
    wndclass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndclass.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wndclass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndclass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndclass.hInstance = hInstance;
    wndclass.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wndclass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(WHITE_BRUSH);
    wndclass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName;
    if (!RegisterClass(&wndclass))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("This program requires Windows NT!"),
            szAppName, MB_ICONERROR);
        return 0;
    }
    hwnd = CreateWindow(szAppName, TEXT("Keyboard Message Viewer #1"),
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
        NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
    ShowWindow(hwnd, iCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hwnd);
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return msg.wParam;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static int cxClientMax, cyClientMax, cxClient, cyClient, cxChar, cyChar;
    static int cLinesMax, cLines;
    static PMSG pmsg;
    static RECT rectScroll;
    static const TCHAR szTop[] = TEXT("Message Key Char ")
        TEXT("Repeat Scan Ext ALT Prev Tran");
    static const TCHAR szUnd[] = TEXT("_______ ___ ____ ")
        TEXT("______ ____ ___ ___ ____ ____");
    static const TCHAR* szFormat[2] = {
    TEXT("%−13s %3d %−15s%c%6u %4d %3s %3s %4s %4s"),
    TEXT("%−13s 0x%04X%1s%c %6u %4d %3s %3s %4s %4s") };
    static const TCHAR* szYes = TEXT("Yes");
    static const TCHAR* szNo = TEXT("No");
    static const TCHAR* szDown = TEXT("Down");
    static const TCHAR* szUp = TEXT("Up");
    static const TCHAR* szMessage[] = {
    TEXT("WM_KEYDOWN"), TEXT("WM_KEYUP"),
    TEXT("WM_CHAR"), TEXT("WM_DEADCHAR"),
    TEXT("WM_SYSKEYDOWN"), TEXT("WM_SYSKEYUP"),
    TEXT("WM_SYSCHAR"), TEXT("WM_SYSDEADCHAR") };
    HDC hdc;
    int i, iType;
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    TCHAR szBuffer[128], szKeyName[32];
    TEXTMETRIC tm;
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
    case WM_DISPLAYCHANGE:
        // Get maximum size of client area
        cxClientMax = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXMAXIMIZED);
        cyClientMax = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYMAXIMIZED);
        // Get character size for fixed−pitch font
        hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
        SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(SYSTEM_FIXED_FONT));
        GetTextMetrics(hdc, &tm);
        cxChar = tm.tmAveCharWidth;
        cyChar = tm.tmHeight;
        ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc);
        // Allocate memory for display lines
        if (pmsg)
            free(pmsg);
        cLinesMax = cyClientMax / cyChar;
```

The following the offending code:

```
        pmsg = (PMSG *)malloc(cLinesMax * sizeof(MSG));
```

Why did it function in the past and now why is it not functioning now?

```
        cLines = 0;
        // fall through
    case WM_SIZE:
        if (message == WM_SIZE)
        {
            cxClient = LOWORD(lParam);
            cyClient = HIWORD(lParam);
        }
        // Calculate scrolling rectangle
        rectScroll.left = 0;
        rectScroll.right = cxClient;
        rectScroll.top = cyChar;
        rectScroll.bottom = cyChar * (cyClient / cyChar);
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, TRUE);
        return 0;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
    case WM_KEYUP:
    case WM_CHAR:
    case WM_DEADCHAR:
    case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
    case WM_SYSKEYUP:
    case WM_SYSCHAR:
    case WM_SYSDEADCHAR:
        // Rearrange storage array
        for (i = cLinesMax - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            pmsg[i] = pmsg[i - 1];
        }
        // Store new message
        pmsg[0].hwnd = hwnd;
        pmsg[0].message = message;
        pmsg[0].wParam = wParam;
        pmsg[0].lParam = lParam;
        cLines = min(cLines + 1, cLinesMax);
        // Scroll up the display
        ScrollWindow(hwnd, 0, -cyChar, &rectScroll, &rectScroll);
        break; // i.e., call DefWindowProc so Sys messages work
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        SelectObject(hdc, GetStockObject(SYSTEM_FIXED_FONT));
        SetBkMode(hdc, TRANSPARENT);
        TextOut(hdc, 0, 0, szTop, lstrlen(szTop));
        TextOut(hdc, 0, 0, szUnd, lstrlen(szUnd));
        for (i = 0; i < min(cLines, cyClient / cyChar - 1); i++)
        {
            iType = pmsg[i].message == WM_CHAR ||
                pmsg[i].message == WM_SYSCHAR ||
                pmsg[i].message == WM_DEADCHAR ||
                pmsg[i].message == WM_SYSDEADCHAR;
            GetKeyNameText(pmsg[i].lParam, szKeyName,
                sizeof(szKeyName) / sizeof(TCHAR));
            TextOut(hdc, 0, (cyClient / cyChar - 1 - i) * cyChar, szBuffer,
                wsprintf(szBuffer, szFormat[iType],
                    szMessage[pmsg[i].message - WM_KEYFIRST],
                    pmsg[i].wParam,
                    (PTSTR)(iType ? TEXT(" ") : szKeyName),
                    (TCHAR)(iType ? pmsg[i].wParam : ' '),
                        LOWORD(pmsg[i].lParam),
                        HIWORD(pmsg[i].lParam) & 0xFF,
                        0x01000000 & pmsg[i].lParam ? szYes : szNo,
                        0x20000000 & pmsg[i].lParam ? szYes : szNo,
                        0x40000000 & pmsg[i].lParam ? szDown : szUp,
                        0x80000000 & pmsg[i].lParam ? szUp : szDown));
        }
        EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: This code looks like 100% C. There is no C++ here. Perhaps you are compiling using the wrong language.

Comment: See [erratum 8](http://jasondoucette.com/books/pw5/pw5errata.html#cplusplus). The cast required in C++ should be made to `(MSG *)` or  `(PMSG)` not `(PMSG *)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59216011/a-value-of-type-void-cannot-be-assigned-to-an-entity-of-type-randomstruct does the job